# using ahk pixel search to trigger hot key

Tags: toggle, autohotkey, pixel

Using pixel search with mousemove/click no probplem. Throw in a send hotkey command and it completely ignores the pixel search as the trigger. this is what I have so far...

```
   loop
```

{
PixelSearch, PX, PY, 1311, 205, 1512, 994, 0x00c8ff, 20, Fast,
If (ErrorLevel = 0)

```
   {
  
    send, f1::
    sleep, 10000

         Send {Alt Down}{Tab} ;Bring up switcher immediately
    KeyWait, F1, T.5  ; Go to next window; wait .5s before looping
    if (Errorlevel)
   {
    While ( GetKeyState( "F1","P" ) ) {
        Send {Tab}
        Sleep, 400 ; wait 400ms before going to next window
    }
}
    Send {Alt Up} ;Close switcher on hotkey release
```

}

Would like when pixel found it would toggle screens. Toggles screens just fine using f1.